# How to detect long click on GoogleMap marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, onlongclicklistener

In my app I have a MapFragment.

I do

```
map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

and after that add a marker in the event

```
onMapClick(LatLng point){
    ...

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .title(txt));

    ...
}
```

All this works perfectly.
What I need is to know when the user keep long click on the marker I put on the map.

I made some handmade calculations in

```
onMapLongClick(LatLng point){
...

if((Math.abs(mrkrPos.latitude-point.latitude)<0.0005)&&(Math.abs(mrkrPos.longitude-point.longitude)<0.0005))

...
}
```

but this isn't obviously a fine way to do it, and it isn't very accurate (only works when zoom camera is at high levels on map)

Comment: Are you ok with the possibility to differentiate between `onMarkerClick` and `onMarkerLongClick` when user lifts up their finger or you need it to be fired after e.g. 400 ms pressing the `Marker`?

Comment: Use javascript for this....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript

Comment: Basically you can use the OnMarkerDragListener

[Check my workaround][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391665/setting-a-longclicklistener-on-a-map-marker

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no long Click Listener for markers. see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391665/setting-a-longclicklistener-on-a-map-marker) about this from a while ago

Comment: Thx, I see the answer given to you it's the same I did. I hoped there was something more accurate :/

Comment: nope, I had do take a different route. Hopefully this will be implemented in the future

Answer (score 0):

Hey take a look at the solution i have given in other thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42885588/3779042