# How to handle Google Map v2 Marker's Long click event in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm developing an android application in which I've used Google Map v2 API.
I've placed one marker on the map, now I want to set its "OnLongClickListener".
As I can see from Eclipse there are only two listeners available for marker:
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);
googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(listener);

Could anybody show me any easy way to handle marker's LongClick event??

I've gone through two solutions here:

1. [Setting a LongClickListener on a map Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391665/setting-a-longclicklistener-on-a-map-marker)
2. [How to detect long click on GoogleMap marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372179/how-to-detect-long-click-on-googlemap-marker)

Comment: if you went through and read the solutions you posted then you would have learned that there is no long click listener for a marker. long clicking is used for dragging markers after they have been placed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as both of the solutions you posted have shown - there is no long click event on markers in the maps api. the first link you posted had a solution that might be able to suit your needs but isn't perfect by any means

i would suggest going [here to the gmaps issues page](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) and browsing through the feature requests and adding one if it does not exist