# How do I import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have done with polygon on Google map, now I want to calculate the area of a  drawn polygon by using `SphericalUtil.computeArea()`, but I am not able to import `com.Google.maps.android.SphericalUtil`.

I have added Google play services and also added

```
uses-library "android:name="com.Google.android.maps"
```

into the manifest.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In **Android Studio** - You have to add following dependency to your Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2'
}
```

Reference - [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)

- **SphericalUtil** class is available under **android-maps-utils**

See [link here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java)

Comment: For the latest version number see https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/releases

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil` is included in the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/), so you need to setup this library in order to import `SphericalUtil`in your project.

Here is the [Google Maps Android API Utility Setup](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup) guide

Answer (score 1):

This works to me:

```
dependencies {
...

   implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

}

from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup
and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup